# How do I upgrade a .NET 2.0 website to 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

My website is VB.NET 2.0.  I already opened a it in VS2k8 and told it not to upgrade.  Now I want to upgrade, how do I trigger it?  All the posts say 'just open it in 2k8 and it will prompt you'.  Well I did, and it did, and I didn't want to yet.  Now I cant get it to come up.

Comment: ok, and what about IIS options? how can I tell IIS that my site now runs .NET 3.5?

Comment: @chester89 - so long as .NET 3.5 is installed on your server, you shouldn't have to worry.  .NET 3.5 actually compiles into IL that is 100% compatible with the the 2.0 CLR.  They just added libraries (e.g. LINQ) and syntactic sugar (e.g. extension methods) that still compile to 2.0 IL.  So, so long as those new libraries are present, you can still even run under the 2.0 app pools in IIS.

Comment: @Matt - so, as I got it right, I need to do only 2 things - choose new target framework in studio and install .net 3.5 to my server?

Comment: If I recall correctly, yes :).  If you're using ASP.NET MVC you'll need to install that on the server as well, though that's not applicable to this particular question (since MVC didn't work on .NET 2.0).

Comment: You can include the MVC dlls in your project instead of installing on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your project properties and choose Target Framework in the Application tab.  There should be values such as ".NET Framework 3.5", ".NET Framework 2.0", etc.  You can access project properties in your Solution Explorer by right-clicking on your project name and choosing Properties from the right-click menu.

If Solution Explorer isn't showing for you in Visual Studio, you can access it via the View menu > Solution Explorer.

Comment: You beat me to it.  Have to remove my anwser.

Comment: I didnt think this worked when I did it, because I got all kinds of errors.  Then I went through each one and fixed it.  It was mostly making things nice for the IDE(VS).  It was simple to work through and I think it worked ok.  Although now I am having trouble with EF not being able to save to my web.config.